# Break out of synchronized block?

Tags: java, synchronized

I have this:

```
synchronized(c){
   if (!items.hasNext() && (c.getFinishedCount() == c.getStartedCount())) {
      f.done(null, results);
      return;
    }

    if(c.isBelowCapacity()){
      RunMap(items,m,results,c,s,f);
    }
}
```

but ultimately I don't need to be synchronized on c when I call `RunMap()` or `f.done()`, I just need to be synchronized on c when I do the conditional checks / if statements.

Should I just make the methods on c synchronized, and then get rid of the synchronized block?

Comment: "Should I just make the methods on c synchronized" you can, but then you will synchronize separately, and that may not be what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should I just make the methods on c synchronized, and then get rid of
>   the synchronized block?

No, the better way is to make the checks within the synchronized block, and then do the rest of the work later:

```
boolean bFDone = false;
boolean bRunMap = false;

synchronized (c) {
    bFDone = !items.hasNext() && (c.getFinishedCount() == c.getStartedCount());
    bRunMap = !bFDone && c.isBelowCapacity();
}

if (bFDone) {
    f.done(null, results);
} else if (bRunMap) {
    RunMap(items,m,results,c,s,f);
}
```

The big advantage of this version is, that all the volatile code is actually synchronized, and the rest (potentially slow) stuff happens later.

As mentioned correctly in the comments to this answer, this only works correctly, if your initial assumption is correct, that the entire block does not need synchronization. If you need to react to the conditions immediately, then the block needs to be in fact synchronized (entirely).

Comment: The big disadvantage, however, is that the conditions which cause you to choose `f.done` or `RunMap` may not be true by the time you come to invoke them.

Comment: Good strategy, but note that the OP must be sure this is what he/she wants. If `runMap()` writes `c`, then it may cause synchronization problems causing inaccurate reads during the `if` checks. If it reads `c` then it may be reading `c` when it is no longer valid.

Comment: This is true, but according to OP, the rest of the code does not need synchronization, so the calls should withstand this. Otherwise OPs assumption is wrong, that the entire code needs not to be synchronized.

Comment: @TreffnonX Yup, I think it is good to warn the OP what are the implications, in case he or she may have not considered that previously.

Answer (score 1):

Making `c`'s methods synchronized is probably a bad idea. First, it means that **whenever** you call them, no matter the context, they will be synchronized, which probably isn't what you meant. Second, it won't help atomically resolving the conditions `!items.hasNext()` and `c.getFinishedCount() == c.getStartedCount()`.

One option is to initialize `boolean` variables inside `synchronized` blocks and then perform the relevant calls outside of them:

```
final boolean isDone;
synchronized(c) {
    isDone = !items.hasNext() && (c.getFinishedCount() == c.getStartedCount());
}

if (isDone) {
    f.done(null, results);
    return;
}

final boolean isBelowCapacity;
synchronized(c) {
    isBelowCapacity =  c.isBelowCapacity();
}

if (isBelowCapacity) {
    RunMap(items,m,results,c,s,f);
}
```

Comment: yes I especially appreciate this observation "First, it means that whenever you call them, no matter the context, they will be synchronized" b/c that's what I was thinking when I posted the question